# Sitecore query not returning results for level 9 items

Tags: sitecore

My sitecore item hierarchy is like this,

/sitecore/content/Public/level1/level2/level3/Item1/Images/Image1

I tried following query in X-Path builder
`/sitecore/content/Public/level1/level2/level3/Item1/Images/Image1/*`
Does not return any result...

but, 1 level above returns results, (All images Image1, Image 2 etc.)
`/sitecore/content/Public/level1/level2/level3/Item1/Images/*`

Following returned Image1 as well,
`/sitecore/content/Public/level1/level2/level3/Item1/Images//*`

(Data and query executed in the master database)

Is this a sitecore query limitation where you can't query single items which has more that 8 levels?

Comment: which version of Sitecore you use? I'm using **Sitecore 6.6 update 3** and 9th and 10th level items are returned in **XPath Builder**

Comment: I'm using Sitecore.NET 6.6.0 (rev. 120918) September 18, 2012

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the part of your content-tree you are trying to query?

Answer (score 1):

Check the setting of the `<setting name="Query.MaxItems" value="100" />` property in the web.config. It is standard set to return only the first 100 items. Raise the limit and see if this might have something to do with your issue.

Comment: If the limit is the issue there the first 100 will be returned. But actually I have only about 5 items under the Image1 item.

Comment: I know, but it could have been a bug or something in the version you use.

Comment: Also, it is worth installing a default version of Sitecore, add some dummy data and running the query against that, just to make sure it isn't something specific in your project.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about some restrictions and think this should work. Your query also looks ok. Are you sure that you have some items available under "Image1"? If you only have the described hierarchy with no childs under "Image1", then you won't get any items returned by the query.

Your last query (with //*) also say that only "Image1" is returned. Because the // defines a recursive query, also childs of "Image1" should be returned, if there are any.

Comment: Items are existing in the Image1 item, but it wont returned by the query. But `//*` will return the items correctly which not returned in previous query.